# VSCode adds spaces inside HTML tags inside React code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, format, linter

Starting to learn React from ground when I saved the code below VS Code formatted it as in the image.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <h1> Hi there  {name} </h1> 
        <p>  your lucky number is {num} </p>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Line breaks with spaces formatted sample code from VSCode:
[image]

I've googled it but some time later I realized that it was the file format that caused this problem.

*Thanks Guillermo, the VSCode extension JS-CSS-HTML Formatter was the cause, uninstalling it and using prettier instead solved the problem.*

Answer (score 2):

I solved by the following steps:

- Install the Prettier-Code formatter.
- Disable the default HTML formatter in settings.
- After that restart your VS-Code.

For more detail please view the under link:

[How to disable the default HTML formatter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAvKz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using a formatter for js files that doesn't get well along with React.

You could try to add this line to your `settings.json` file:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

(Provided you have [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) installed)

Comment: This has worked for me afterall, I've used create-react-app to be sure of any syntax errors, when I changed the default formatter to prettier, it has added several spaces usign this format `{" "}`. 

Even though the default formatter is prettier, this old extension JS-CSS-HTML Formatter was preventing new files to be formatted with prettier.

Uninstalling JS-CSS-HTML Formatter solved my problem. Thank you @guillermo-brachetta

Answer (score 0):

Change the file type from javascript to javascript react

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7hYJ.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).