# in a react app using visual studio code, I cant able to add the html tags to ReactDOM.render file

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render( < h1 > Hello WOrld! < /h1>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Not sure, but the problem can be in this line - < h1 > Hello WOrld! < /h1>, try without spaces

<h1> Hello WOrld! </h1>

Also, you should not do such things in ReactDOM.render. 

Following the best practices, ReactDOM.render(...., root) should be used only for attaching entry components, like <App /> for example

Comment: after creating it in a component App.jsx, iam facing the same problem and the spacing with<h1> tags are automatically gets when i save the APP.jsx page

Comment: Do you have an `index.html` file? Is there an element with the `root` id?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In the `<head>` section of the HTML file add the following link

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<!-- Load Babel -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Now, in the bottom of the `<body>` tag add:

```html
<script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

Next, click the vscode extension icon and search for live server and install it. Finally, right click your HTML file and select the option *"Open with live server"*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this. The VS Code's behavior is really strange, this spaces around the h1 tag appear with saving the code.

If you rename the `index.js` to `index.jsx` and remove the spaces around the h1, then the save function will not break it again.

Then when I run it with `npm run start`, the code works fine.
Good luck, anyway I'd recommend to use the App.jsx component instead of the `<h1>` directly in the ReactDOM.render method.

When the problem remains you need to play with the VSCode Settings > Extensions > HTML > Format: Enable

uncheck `Enable/disable default HTML formatter.`

check also this answer:

[1]: [VSCode adds spaces inside HTML tags inside React code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65979939/vscode-adds-spaces-inside-html-tags-inside-react-code) ,
there is a nice picture - it will solve it definitely.

Comment: import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import APP from "./App"

ReactDOM.render( <
    div >
    <
    APP / >
    <
    /div>,
    document.getElementById("root")); this is my APP.jsx page iam facing the same issue even after changing the file name into .Jsx

Comment: import React from "react";

function App() {
    return ( < h1 > Hello World! < /h1>);
    }

    export default App This is my APP.jsx file page here to iam getting the same error which creates its space in < h1 > once i saved the file

Comment: I have updated the answer above with the settings